# Red Hat Linux - port is in listening state but could not find process ID

Tags: process, ps, netstat, lsof, port

I have this problem for my application, port is in listening state but process ID is not showing up. Used below commands. This is cloud AWS server Red Hat Linux.

```
$ netstat -tulpn

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8008            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN       


$ netstat -ltpnae | awk 'NR==2 || /:8008/'

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8008            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          142518     -

$ lsof | awk 'NR==1 || /142518/'

COMMAND    PID   TID    USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
```

Comment: Try using sudo ss -lnp | grep ":8008"

Comment: sudo ss -lnp | grep ":8008"
                                                                                                                                   
   tcp    LISTEN     0      100       *:8008                  *:*

Answer (score 1):

You should also see this info or similar:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
```

This is a security feature - hiding unowned processes. That's why you see `-` at the end.

Try the commands with `sudo` or as root.

Comment: yes i have performed all these as root user only.

Comment: @vamshi Are you completely sure?

Comment: yes tomasz.....